# Looking up a Mongo collection, keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm running into a strange problem with a very simple and straightforward JS code. Here, I'm trying to look up a given (email) value against a database and return a boolean true if a record with that value exists:

```
// utils/isEmailInDB.js
import User from '../models/user';

const isEmailInDB = (email) => {
  let emailExists;
  User.findOne({ emails: email }).then((existingUser) => {
    if(existingUser) { emailExists = true; } else { emailExists = false; }
  });
  return emailExists;
};
export default isEmailInDB;
```

In another file, I'm calling this function and logging the returned value to the screen:

```
// routes/mail-routes.js
import express from 'express';
import sendEmail from '../utils/sendEmail';
import isEmailInDB from '../utils/isEmailInDB';

import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', [
  check('to').isEmail(),
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  const { to = '', pageURL = '/' } = req.body;
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.redirect(pageURL + '?verify=1');
  } else {
    // Generate token
    // Check if email exists in db
    const existsInDB = isEmailInDB(to);
    console.log('EMAIL EXISTS?', existsInDB);
    sendEmail(to).then(() => {
      res.redirect(pageURL + '?verify=2');
    }).catch((err) => {
      res.redirect(pageURL + '?verify=1');
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

With this line in the second snippet above: `console.log('EMAIL EXISTS?', existsInDB);`, I expect to see one of the following outputs upon execution, depending on whether the email exists in DB:

> EMAIL EXISTS? true
>
> EMAIL EXISTS? false

However, no matter what I try, the line keeps returning *undefined*. Even when the email being looked up exists. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: can you share code for `isEmailInDB`?? My guess is it performs some async operation and must be dealt in such way.

Comment: Already shared...it's the first snippet in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Promises or `asyn-await` with the `isEmailInDB` function, because it is NOT waiting for the `User.find` to complete. Also, when you are calling the function it is again not waiting for the async function to complete as well.

```
const isEmailInDB = async (email) => {
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ emails: email });
  return !!existingUser;
};
```

In the route:

```
router.post('/', [
  check('to').isEmail(),
], async (req, res) => {
    .
    .
    const existsInDB = await isEmailInDB(to);
    .
    .
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined as the the return statement is immediately executed and at that time `existingUser` is undefined. What you could is instead return a promise a true or false value and use this promise in your mail routes file.

Update your `isEmailInDB` code.

```
// utils/isEmailInDB.js
import User from '../models/user';

const isEmailInDB = (email) => {
  let emailExists;
  return User.findOne({ emails: email })
  .then((existingUser) => {
     return { emailExists = !!existingUser };

  });
};
export default isEmailInDB;
```

and in your mail routes use this instead

```
const existsInDB = isEmailInDB(to);
existsInDB.then((existsInDB) => {
  console.log('EMAIL EXISTS?', existsInDB);
  sendEmail(to).then(() => {
    res.redirect(pageURL + '?verify=2');
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.redirect(pageURL + '?verify=1');
  });
})
```

Comment: You need to return the Promise from `isEmailInDB` otherwise it will not work.

Comment: yeah you are right. fixed it. Thanks